# How to see trac code browser in a web browser?

Tags: trac

I have a project "QHG3" in an `svn` repository located at "/home/morpho_svn" on my server  and have created a Trac environment with

```
sudo  trac-admin /home/users/QHG/TracQHG3 initenv
```

where i gave the project name as 'QHG3'.

Then i started `tracd`

```
 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/tracd --daemonize --pidfile=/var/run/tracd.pid --port=8000 -s /home/users/QHG/TracQHG3/
```

I would now like to see the code browser. When i use the URL `http://my_server:8000/TracQHG3/browser/QHG3` i get the error "No handler matched request to /TracQHG3/browser/QHG3"

(i copied this URL from an older installation with functioning code browser)

I suspect i missed a step somewhere because i don't see were the assosiation between the Trac environment and my svn repository is made.

Are there any additional steps i need to take?
What URL should i use to see the code browser?

(edit: corrected typo (TracQHG3 instead of TracQHG4 in the URL)

The component section of trac.ini:

```
[components]
tracopt.versioncontrol.svn.* = enabled
```

And repositories

```
[repositories]
.dir = /home/morpho_svn
.type =  svn
```

section version control:

```
[versioncontrol]
allowed_repository_dir_prefixes =
default_repository_type = svn
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either omit the -s switch or remove TracQHG3 from the path and just navigate to `http://my_server:8000` and `http://my_server:8000/browser`. The -s switch implies a single project, and the project name is not included in the path.

You need to [enable svn support](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#Enablingthecomponents) and then [configure the repositories](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#Repositories) through the page `http://my_server:8000/TracQHG4/admin/versioncontrol` or by editing trac.ini.

Comment: When i do ```http://my_server:8000/TracQHG3/admin/versioncontrol``` i also get the error "No handler matched request to /TracQHG3/admin/versioncontrol". In my trac.ini under "[repositories] i have two entries: ```.dir = /home/morpho_svn``` and ```type =  svn```. Under "[versioncontrol}" ihave the entries ```default_repository_type = svn``` and ```allowed_repository_dir_prefixes = ```, ```trac-admin /home/aim-bigfoot/QHG/TracQHG3/ repositories list``` gives me ```(default)  svn          /home/morpho_svn``` which looks ok to me. trac.ini is read because the header-logo i specified is displayed.

Comment: You need to [enable the svn connector](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#Enablingthecomponents). On navigating to `/admin/versioncontrol` you should see `Unknown administration panel` if no repository connectors are enabled. Please edit your original post and include the `[components]` section of trac.ini.

Comment: When i go to ```http://my_server:8000/TracQHG3/admin/versioncontrol``` i get the "No handler matched request to /TracQHG3/admin/versioncontrol" message. The same for ```http://my_server:8000/TracQHG3```

Comment: It seems the entire installation is broken. I would start by [checking the logs](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTroubleshooting#ChecktheLogs). You might try a simpler invocation of Trac as well: `/usr/bin/tracd --port=8000 -s /home/users/QHG/TracQHG3`. Which Trac version?

Comment: The version of tracd is "tracd 1-4".

Comment: The version of tracd is "tracd 1-4". When i start it with the command you suggested, i get two WARNINGs: ``` [trac] base_url option not set in configuration, generated links may be incorrect``` and ```[130.60.126.101] HTTPNotFound: 404 Not Found (No handler matched request to /TracQHG3), <RequestWithSession "GET '/TracQHG3'">, referrer None```. There follows a large number of DEBUGs like ```Trac[perm] DEBUG: No policy allowed anonymous performing g TRAC_ADMIN on <Resource u'admin:general/basics'>```

Comment: On second look the error is obvious, I should have caught it earlier. Either omit the `-s` switch or remove `TracQHG3` from the path and just navigate to `http://my_server:8000` and `http://my_server:8000/browser`. The `-s` switch implies single project, and the project name is not included in the path.

Comment: Removing the "-s" worked. I can now see the code of the two projects in ```morpho_svn` code in the browser  - thanks!

Comment: Now i added a new project to the repository and restarted tracd (without the '-s'). The  two old projects can still be browsed, but the new one is not. The new project can be seen with the ```svn list```-command, so it certainly is in the repository. Do i have to take special steps to make trac aware of the new project?

Comment: Trac can connect to repositories using two modes: cached and non-cached. For cached repositories, there is explicit or implicit synchronization. Cached explicit sync is the best performance but the most complex to config. To start, you can enable non-cached access by changed `.type = svn` -> `.type = direct-svnfs`. You can enable cached implicit sync with `.type = svn` and `.sync_per_request = true`. See if either offers sufficient page load performance (browse repository files and changesets). See [TracRepositioryAdmin](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#Usingtrac-svn-hook).

Comment: Thanks - with ".type = direct-svnfs" i can now browse the code of all projects in the repository. There seems to be no noticeable performance hit with these settings.

Comment: Often performance with a small repository will be fine. You may need to change to explicit synchronization if you add more repositories and/or your repositories grow large.